# pandas sort more than one column not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to sort a numerical column (desc) and a text column (asc) but it is not working as expected in pandas.

Here is my code:

```
df.sort_values(by=['values', 'name'], ascending=[False, True])
```

The values are showing desc but the names are not in ascending order.

This is the desired result I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: The result you show is sorted by name first, then by value, which is the opposite of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order on how we sort the values:

```
df.sort_values(by=['name', 'values'], ascending=[True, False])
```

We have to sort it by `name` first, and then `values`. Not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it back and switch

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['name', 'values'], ascending=[True, False])
```